# Are data URI links permanent?

Tags: javascript, html, uri, data-uri

So in this website I am making, the user is able to upload an image and then preview that image all on the same page.

If I right click the image that is being previewed (as a thumbnail) and click on "View Image", it will open the image in a new tab with this super long data URI.

I was wondering, are data URI's permanent (as long as the website doesn't get deleted or something)?

If I upload an image on my website, get a data URI, and don't ever delete the website, then would the data URI still be valid a year later, from any device (that can connect to the internet and access a browser) anywhere in the world? Would I still be able to view that same photo I uploaded a year ago?

Comment: How do you get the URI? How is it generated? Do you use a library/framework for this?

Comment: It depends how you generate the URI. Also, it shouldn't be something a user can guess what it'll be otherwise they could use it to upload malicious files.

Comment: Gifs are still readable after 33 years. How static do you need the format to be?

Comment: @dan1st  I use a file reader and then call reader.readAsDataUrl(file[0]). I want to store this data URI in a database so that it can be displayed using the html tag <img src = "data uri"> when the user enters the image ID associated with that data URI on another page.I used this code on my project - http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/

The programming language I am using on the backend does not let me store the actual image into the database itself, so I was hoping to store its uri.

Comment: @learningtoanimate see my reply to Dan

Comment: @mplungjan i have set it so that the user can only upload jpg, jpeg, and png files. Any other file and they will be presented with an error message when they try to upload it.

Also, see my response to Dan for more info on what I am trying to do along with some sample code.

Comment: And what are your concerns? That the browser will not be able to decode an image data uri in the future? It will likely exist for another 10 years at least if not longer. And if not, your DB can convert it to jpeg2030 when the time comes

Comment: @mplungjan Perfect! That is what I needed to know, thanks!